# No longer able to use 127.0.0.1 redirect_uri

Tags: ssl, redirect, microsoft-graph-api

I am debugging an app that uses Microsoft Graph.  Along the way I learned that the redirect_uri wants to be over SSL, but I could work around this for testing by using 127.0.0.1.   This evening I noticed this is no longer working:

> The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The scope 'User.Read offline_access Calendars.ReadWrite' requires that the request must be sent over a secure connection using SSL

I can't believe that we have to use SSL for testing.   Is there a setting someplace to disable this restriction?

Comment: Have you tried `http://localhost`?

Comment: I did now and indeed localhost works.   I don't recall how I got on 127.0.0.1to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use an IP address for the `redirect_uri`, you need to use `localhost` instead.